Chromium not start after update to 123
After update to chromium 123.0.6312.122, the app do not start and gives this message:
cannot update snap namespace: cannot expand mount entry (none $HOME/.local/share none x-snapd.kind=ensure-dir,x-snapd.must-exist-dir=$HOME 0 0): cannot use invalid home directory "/home/myuser": permission denied
snap-update-ns failed with code 1

It happens only for one of my users, others works fine. I try uninstall, restart, install. I want to revert to previous version, by snap list chromium do not offer other version. I use Ubuntu 22.04 Pro.

I also have this problem. Did you find solution ?

No, I didnt find solution. Maybe installing the flatpak version or adding older version from debian repository could help, but I didnt try yet. It is strange that it happend just for one of my users,  so I suspect that the problem is not in the version itself.

I am also encountering this but with a different snap package. Do you have an encrypted home directory?

Yes, I have and that's a very good clue, because it is only broken for a user with encrypted home directory

I found solution here and it worked. Please check for yourself:
chromium fails to start with non-standard home directory

This is also reproducible on 124.0.6367.60

This is bug 2061981 affecting users of Snapd 2.62. (So your attempt to revert Chromium wouldn't work, given the timing understandable to conclude that the Chromium update was the problem, a mistake nonetheless.)
Work-around while the fix doesn't land in Snapd stable channel:
Option 1:
sudo snap refresh --edge snapd

Option 2 (for Chromium only):
snap disconnect chromium:dot-local-share-applications
snap disconnect chromium:dot-local-share-icons

Once the fix lands in Snapd stable you will want to revert the changes you chose to apply.

I waited a couple of weeks, the fix did not yet land in Snapd stable. (At least not on Ubuntu 22.04.1)

@w-sky, Snapd is complicated, it's is available as a snap and as a deb, I don't really grasp the difference but it might be only installed as a deb in your system, if snap info snapd|grep installed: doesn't return, try snap install snapd and see if the problem is solved.
