Chromium won't start: "cannot update snap namespace: cannot expand mount entry..." Ubuntu 22.04.4
The Chromium snap has stopped working in my computer. I am getting the following error message when I try to run chromium-browser in the terminal:
cannot update snap namespace: cannot expand mount entry (none $HOME/.local/share none x-snapd.kind=ensure-dir,x-snapd.must-exist-dir=$HOME 0 0): cannot use invalid home directory "/home/my-username": permission denied
I'm not sure what to do. Any tips would be very welcome! Thanks in advance!

I'm having the same problem with Slack. Found this question first but it appears to be a duplicate. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1510656/chromium-not-start-after-update-to-123/1510756

There is currently a known issue with the chromium-browser snap that is being worked on: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/2061981
It mainly affects people with non-standard home directories (eg. /home/department/username) as well as encrypted home directories. According to the report, a fix is under way.
A temporary workaround is also proposed in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/2061981/comments/9 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/2061981/comments/12
snap disconnect chromium:dot-local-share-applications
snap disconnect chromium:dot-local-share-icons

and optionally you may
snap revert snapd

until a fix for snapd is released.

I had trouble starting Slack on ubuntu and snap revert snapd fixed it for me. Thanks!

The revert worked for me to start Slack again (thank!) but is this at all related to the Chromium bug then?

Supposedly yes, since Slack et al. are Electron based applications which are, essentially, a wrapper around Chromium.

Do the "snap disconnect" lines need to be undone in anyway once the fixed version is released, or will that happen automatically through the update process?

snap revert snapd also helped me to solved problems with Slack and chromium
